# how do you know if document is ready

Tags: jquery

I have a JavaScript that generates HTML blocks. This script is sometimes called somewhere in run time, and sometimes before document is loaded. I want a script that is able to tell if document is ready. If so, generate the HTML, otherwise, add a document.ready() function. What is jQuery's best way to know if document has been loaded?

Comment: There have been many suggestions for it already, but using `$(document).ready()` really is exactly what you want. Behind the scenes, when this function is called, jQuery checks to see if the DOM is ready. If it is, it simply executes the contained function. If it's not, it adds the ready event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe to always wrap that HTML generation code in $(document).ready().  If the document is already ready, a newly registered $(document).ready() callback will execute immediately.

Answer (score 7):

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        //code to execute once the page is loaded
    }
);
```

Comment: +1 This is a good solution, since it doesn't seem as though OP is worried about images being fully downloaded.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) event:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // your code...
});
```

With `load` event, the DOM, images, frames and any other external resources are loaded into the document.

Comment: You don't even need that much. You can simply do `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: `$(document).load()` doesn't work. Test it: http://jsfiddle.net/kjZrn/ You would need `$(window).load()` or `$(document).ready()` (or equivalent shortcut).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ready event to run things after the DOM is loaded

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  // your function
});
```

or the load event to wait until absolutely everything is loaded

```
$(document).load( function() {
  // your function
});
```

Unless you know you need to use the load event, I would use the ready one (which I believe is the DOMContentLoaded event).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    // document has loaded at this point
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this as well. I have an auto-hide mechanism that triggers too fast while the rest of the document loads (if that's when it's shown in the first place). I solved fairly easily by adding a global boolean that is flipped to TRUE on document.ready().

At the top of my JS:

```
var documentReady = false;
```

My onReady funtion:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    documentReady = true;
    ...
}
```