# load function when everything is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have jquery function that need to implement in .aspx file, in that file `divs` are generating on run time so my requirement is when all the structure is loaded then my function should load.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do you know if document is ready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549379/how-do-you-know-if-document-is-ready)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either put your code in the [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // your code
});
```

Which is also equivalent to:

```
$(function() {
  // your code
});
```

Or execute your function at the *end* of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a `<script />` action at the end of your page or use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// actions to perform
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are a lot of situations when

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// actions to perform
};
```

will not work as desire. For example, when you have content that is generated by JavaScript after the page is loaded (because it takes a lot of time or it is waiting for information from server).

So, what I usually use is combination of these:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    (function IsElementLoaded(){
        //you can check for desire element(s) changing the jquery selector
        if($('#MyElementID').length==0){
            setTimeout(IsElementLoaded(),100);
        }else{
            //your code
        }
    }());
});
```